# Javascript: Filter a JSON conditionally based on the value of a key?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object

After retrieving a JSON such as this:

```
"JSON": [
{
  "mySchool": "college",
  "myHome": "apartment",
  "myFavoriteSport": "soccer"
},
{
  "mySchool": "highschool",
  "myHome": "house",
  "myFavoriteSport": "hockey"
},
{
  "mySchool": "college",
  "myHome": "box",
  "myFavoriteSport": "soccer"
},
{
  "mySchool": "elementary",
  "myHome": "tent",
  "myFavoriteSport": "soccer"
}
]
```

How could I filter it conditionally so that... if `soccer` is the value of `myFavoriteSport` key, then return an array of all objects containing the `myFavoriteSport: soccer` pair? I'm sure I'll end up `pushing`the object into the array at the end, but I don't quite know how to single it out so that I can assign it to a variable.

I'm sure it will involve some type of loop, but this is my first time working with JSON and objects of this type so I'm a little unsure of how to approach it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to filter, then use `.filter` - just check if the `myFavoriteSport` property is `soccer`:

```js
const input = {
  "JSON": [
    {
      "mySchool": "college",
      "myHome": "apartment",
      "myFavoriteSport": "soccer"
    },
    {
      "mySchool": "highschool",
      "myHome": "house",
      "myFavoriteSport": "hockey"
    },
    {
      "mySchool": "college",
      "myHome": "box",
      "myFavoriteSport": "soccer"
    },
    {
      "mySchool": "elementary",
      "myHome": "tent",
      "myFavoriteSport": "soccer"
    }
  ]
};
console.log(
  input.JSON.filter(({ myFavoriteSport }) => myFavoriteSport === 'soccer')
);
```

Also note that JSON is a way of representing an object *in string format*. (for example,

```
const myJSON = '[{"foo":"bar"},{"baz":"buzz"}]';
```

). If you have the actual object/array, then it's not in JSON format - it's just a plain object. Better to name the key something like `arr` or `personArr` or something like that. [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: So I gave it a try and received a lot of errors. 
`(node:62645) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined at Object.module.exports.handler` is one of them

Comment: This is the other `at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
(node:62645) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catchblock, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().`

Comment: You didn't specify the name of the object variable your `"JSON"` property is in, so it's impossible to say from here exactly what the code should be - whatever the variable name is, substitute that into the place where `input` is in the code in my answer. eg `myObj.JSON.filter` or something like that.

Comment: I thought I did specify it like this `const data = JSON.parse(response);` and then using the code in your answer, `console.log(
    data.JSON.filter(({ myFavoriteSport }) => myFavoriteSport === 'Soccer')
  );`

Comment: I console.logged `data` and I know it logs the JSON properly

Comment: Almost, that should work, if `response` is a JSON string containing the object in your question, except that your `'Soccer'` should be `'soccer'` (lower case), see https://jsfiddle.net/qs1mpfy0/

Comment: It works just fine for me, it returns an array containing the three objects with `soccer`. Sounds like a problem with your browser? Were there any errors? Because you used `JSON.parse` to turn the string into an object beforehand, that shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181790/discussion-between-austin-burke-and-certainperformance).

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to achieve with [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) array method, there is a one line solution: you can specify a condition inside a callback function, and finally you will get a new array of items, which fits this condition.

```js
const JSON = [
  {
    "mySchool": "college",
    "myHome": "apartment",
    "myFavoriteSport": "soccer"
  },
  {
    "mySchool": "highschool",
    "myHome": "house",
    "myFavoriteSport": "hockey"
  },
  {
    "mySchool": "college",
    "myHome": "box",
    "myFavoriteSport": "soccer"
  },
  {
    "mySchool": "elementary",
    "myHome": "tent",
    "myFavoriteSport": "soccer"
  }
];

const result = JSON.filter(item => item.myFavoriteSport === 'soccer');
console.log(result);
```

You can also achieve such result using many other array iteration methods, but `filter` perfectly fits your needs.